# How to sort lines with respect to user defined specific order for one item?

Tags: python, file, sorting

I have a file with full of these lines:

> ATOM   4703  CA  GLN D  328   102.64   45.75   42.46  1.00236.44  C

I'd like to sort them with respect to 4th item (`line.split()[4]`, which is D for this case) in a specific order such as first lines with D,
              then lines with E,
then lines with A etc.

so far, my python code is following:

```
for counter in range(3):
   if counter == 0:
        if line.split()[4] == 'D':    
                outputFile.write(line)
   if counter == 1:
        if line.split()[4] == 'E':   
                outputFile.write(line)
   if counter == 2:
        if line.split()[4] == 'A':     
                outputFile.write(line)`
```

However, it only gets lines containing D. Any help?

Comment: Remember that in python, indentation matters, the two last `if` statements should be aligned with the first one. Try this fixing the indentation.

Comment: In my script, they are aligned:(

Comment: Show the outer loop, where you loop through all the lines. I think that the problem is that, to solve this problem the way you intend, you should run the loop three times: in the first iteration print those lines whose value is 'D', in the second iteration those with 'A' and so on.

Comment: I've found the problem. To loop through every line, I have to reopen the input file again. Is there a trick for that you know, rendon? Or should I have to open and close file every time I want to loop through all lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that, to solve this problem the way you intend, you should run the loop three times: in the first iteration print those lines whose value is `D`, in the second iteration those with `A` and so on. Your code should look like this:

```
# Store the lines in an array, this way you don't to reopen the file.
f = open('filename')
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if line.split()[4] == 'D':
        print line

for line in lines:
    if line.split()[4] == 'E':
        print line

for line in lines:
    if line.split()[4] == 'A':
        print line
```

Comment: Definetly! It works! Thank you. So, not to open and close file every time, I should read file with readlines. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort the lines, so why not to use `list.sort` with a key function?

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

ordering = ['D', 'E', 'A']

lines.sort(key=lambda x: ordering.index(x.split()[4]))

for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Although not recommended, if the lambda expression seems to complicated you can use a full function definition for the `key` as following:

```
def key(line):
    splitted = line.split()
    return ordering.index(splitted[4])

lines.sort(key=key)
```